# Add property to object in nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array with objects, for example :

```
data1 = [
{
    "name": "Name-A",
    "image": "images/a.png",
    "prices": [
        {
            "name": "c1",
            "buy": "10",
            "sell": "11"
        },
        {
            "name": "c2",
            "buy": "16",
            "sell": "15"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Name-B",
    "image": "images/b.png",
    "prices": [
        {
            "name": "c1",
            "buy": 11,
            "sell": 12
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Name-C",
    "image": "images/c.png",
    "prices": [
        {
            "name": "c3",
            "buy": 123,
            "sell": 124
        }
    ]
}]
```

Here, I want to add the ranks to particular name based on ranks stored in other API link, for example :

```
data2=[{
    "name": "cs1",
    "symbol": "C1",
    "id": 1
},
{
    "name": "cs2",
    "symbol": "C2",
    "rank": 2,
    "id": 1027
},
 {...}, 
 {...}
 ....]
```

So the result array should be like,

```
[ {
    "name": "Name-A",
    "image": "images/a.png",
    "prices": [
        {
            "name": "c1",
            "rank": 1,
            "buy": "10",
            "sell": "11"
        },
        {
            "name": "c2",
            "rank": 2,
            "buy": "16",
            "sell": "15"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Name-B",
    "image": "images/b.png",
    "prices": [
        {
            "name": "c1",
            "rank": 1,
            "buy": 11,
            "sell": 12
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Name-C",
    "image": "images/c.png",
    "prices": [
        {
            "name": "c3",
            "rank": 3,
            "buy": 123,
            "sell": 124
        }
    ]
}]
```

I need to compare first two array of objects and need to get `rank` in 3rd array.
The first two arrays are compared with `name` and `symbol` of both the 1st two arrays respectively.
I have tried using `map` in javascript but the resultant array contains same `rank` in all the objects , probably rank of the last object.

My code:

```
{
 data1.map((cd)=>{
 cd.prices.map((p)=>{
  data2.map((r)=>{
   if(r.symbol.toUpperCase() === p.name.toUpperCase()){
     cd.prices.forEach(function(cs){
     cs.rank = r.rank;
  });
  }
})
```

})
}

How can this be done so that I get the resultant array of objects with rank in it? I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` to loop, function `map` to avoid `data1.prices` modifications and `find` to look for a specific object with the `rank` value.

```js
var data1 = [{    "name": "Name-A",    "image": "images/a.png",    "prices": [        {            "name": "c1",            "buy": "10",            "sell": "11"        },        {            "name": "c2",            "buy": "16",            "sell": "15"        }    ]},{    "name": "Name-B",    "image": "images/b.png",    "prices": [        {            "name": "c1",            "buy": 11,            "sell": 12        }    ]},{    "name": "Name-C",    "image": "images/c.png",    "prices": [        {            "name": "c3",            "buy": 123,            "sell": 124        }    ]}];
var data2=[{    "name": "cs1",    "symbol": "C1",    "rank": 1,    "id": 1},{    "name": "cs2",    "symbol": "C2",    "rank": 2,    "id": 1027},{    "name": "cs3",    "symbol": "C3",    "rank": 3,    "id": 10276}];

var result = data1.map((o) => {
    // This is to avoid data1 modification.
  var newObj = { ...o, prices: o.prices.map((pp) => ({...pp})) }; 
  
  newObj.prices.forEach((p) => {
    var found = data2.find((d) => d.symbol.toUpperCase() === p.name.toUpperCase());
    if (found) p.rank = found.rank;
  });
  
  return newObj;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```